# Why is jQuery animate() forcing the bottom of my page down?

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate, slide

Here is the site in question:
http://igs.link-networkonline.com/campaign-landing-page/

You can see all the boxes function as they should but when you hover over any of they the bottom of the page extends down further. This used to happen the the div directly below until I used `position: absolute` to hold it in place. I cannot do this with the bottom of the page. Any ideas?

I have already tried animating negative margins and padding with no luck.

I know this isn't the most efficient way to do this but I do not know jQuery too well.
My code:

```
$(function() {


$(".first").hover(function() {
    $(".first").animate({'height': '287px', 'top': "-270px"});
    $("img.button1").animate({'top': "-235px"});
    $('img.button1').attr('src','<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/downarrow.png');
    $("body").animate({'padding-bottom': '-300px'});
}, function() {
    $(".first").animate({'height': '75px', 'top': "-58px", 'overflow': "hidden"});
    $("img.button1").animate({'top': "-25px"});
    $('img.button1').attr('src','<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/bluebutton.png');
});
   $(".second").hover(function() {
        $(".second").animate({'height': '285px', 'top': "-268px"});
        $("img.button2").animate({'top': "-235px"});
        $('img.button2').attr('src','<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/downarrow.png');
    }, function() {
        $(".second").animate({'height': '75px', 'top': "-58px"});
        $("img.button2").animate({'top': "-25px"});
        $('img.button2').attr('src','<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/bluebutton.png');
    });
    $(".third").hover(function() {
        $(".third").animate({'height': '260px', 'top': "-243px"});
        $("img.button3").animate({'top': "-210px"});
        $('img.button3').attr('src','<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/downarrow.png');
    }, function() {
        $(".third").animate({'height': '75px', 'top': "-58px"});
        $("img.button3").animate({'top': "-25px"});
        $('img.button3').attr('src','<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/bluebutton.png');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make the `#slidebottom`s bigger, you are causing `#container` also to grow which in turn overflows off the bottom of the page. You need to take the `#slidebottom`s out of the document flow (by floating or by `position:absolute` so when they get bigger, they dont cause `#container` to get bigger.

Also, IDs need to be unique. You can't have three elements on a page with `id="slidebottom"`. That being said, you should also run your HTML through a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/). This might also catch errors that may be contributing to your problem.

Comment: brilliant, why didn't I think to absolutely positioning that block rather than the one below, duh! thanks for the insight. I'll let you know how it turns out :)

Answer (score 1):

Oh i think i understand what is going on there. It gets to full height before it gets pulled up. Try to have it at 285px height all the time and use z-index to place it behind the green area to hide the 3 tabs, this way the page height won't get modified anymore.

Also it's a good idea to cut down on jQuery when you can use css. So you could add a class for those arrows that change from up to down (use .img-down for one image and img-up for the other for example) and interchange them with $('img').removeClass().addClass('.img-up'), you could take it a step further and remove the jQuery animations in favor of keyframe animations in css (but in your case i think browser compatibility is a issue)

Since they all have the same animation a function would go along nicely so let's say

```
 $('.first').hover(function(){
   pullUp($(this));
 }) // same goes for .second .third etc.

 var pullUp = function($this) {
    $this.animate({'top': "-270px"});
 }
```

Removed the height part since you can make that magic happen in css

Comment: Thanks for all these tips! i am trying to right out hte correct functions now :)

Answer (score 1):

Give your `#content` div some height. I randomly added:

```
<div id="content" style="height:300px;">
```

and it seems to work. If you can design to a fixed size, this might be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#bottom` is somehow being pushed down.

By using `margin-top: -148px` instead of putting `top: -243px` (in case of .third, different values for .second and .first) it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative margin-top instead of negative top. Hope it would be helpful.